# TensorFlow object detection api: classification weights initialization when changing number of classes at training using pre-trained models

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, object-detection-api

I want to utilize not only the feature-extractor pre-trained weights but also the feature-map layers' classifier/localization pre-trained weights for fine-tuning tensorflow object detection models (SSD) using tensorflow object detection API. When my new model has a different number of classes from the pre-trained model that I'm using for the fine-tuning checkpoint, how would the TensorFlow object detection API handle the classification weight tensors?

When fine-tuning pre-trained models in ML object detection models like SSD, I can initialize not only the feature-extractor weights with the pre-trained weights but also initialize the feature-map's localization layer weights and classification layer weights, with latter only choosing the pre-trained class weights of choice, so that I can decrease the number of classes that the model can initially identify (for example from 90 MSCOCO classes to whichever classes of choice within those 90 classes like cars & pedestrian only etc.)
https://github.com/pierluigiferrari/ssd_keras/blob/master/weight_sampling_tutorial.ipynb
This is how it's done in keras models (ie in h5 files) and I want to do the same in Tensorflow object detection API as well. It seems that at training time I can specify the number of classes the new model is going to have in the config protobuf file, but since I'm new to the API (and tensorflow) I haven't been able to follow the source structure and understand how that number is going to be handled at fine-tuning. Most SSD models I know just ignore and initialize the classification weight tensor in case the pre-trained model's class weight shape is different from the new model's classification weight shape, but I want to retain the necessary classification weights and train upon those. Also, how would I do that within the API structure?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I read through the code I found the responsible code, which only retains the pre-trained model's weights if the shape of the layers between the newly-defined model and the pre-trained model match. So if I change the number of the class, the shape of the classifier layers change, and the pre-trained weights are not retained.

https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/utils/variables_helper.py#L133

Comment: Hello @Kazuya, 
does "the pre-trained weights are not retained" also include the feature-extractor pre-trained weight?
Thank you so much for asking this question because it bothers me too!!!

Comment: Hi @willSapgreen, no it does not include the feature-extractor pre-trained weights. It seems that when the class numbers change, only the classification layers' weights are initialized, while the feature-extractor and localization layers' weights are retained because their shape does not change according to the number of classes.

Comment: Hello @Kazuya Hatta, thank you for the quick response. Another question I have is are both classification layers' and feature-extractors/localization layers' weights updated during the training?
This is why I ask this following question:
https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/6129/getting-worse-performance-when-training-a-pre-trained-model-with-the-existing-cl

Comment: @willSapgreen yes I think they are updated. Regarding your question in ai.stackexchange did you properly set the class number to 1, and made the tfrecord file correctly? If everything is done according to the documents and getting unreasonable results the other possibility is that your data is not properly annotated

Comment: thank you for the feedback. I will double check the tfrecord( extract the image data from it). Another question is in your experience, any other approach to debug the bag performance( like check the weights in classification layers ) besides looking at "total loss" and "mAP"? Thank you.

Comment: I occasionally check how my model is doing by making predictions using the model, and make sure it's getting better. On the charts I only look at the losses though.

Comment: It makes sense. @Kazuya. In these two days I found out there is a positive correlation between my total loss and the number of groundtruth boxes in the training image. I update this information to the link above. Please let me know if any suggestion if you are interested in. Thank you for precious time on this.

Comment: Hello @Kazyua, I found this discussion and learn how to freeze the FeatureExtractor layers' weights when training. https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/2203. Another thing I want to confirm is based on "So if I change the number of the class, the shape of the classifier layers change, and the pre-trained weights are not retained.", the BoxPredictor layers' wights will be initialized randomly if the numbers of classes are different. Correct? Thank you!

Comment: @willSapgreen yes partially true, the BoxPredictor layers are made of two parts: localization layers and classification layers, and my understanding is that the classification layers’ weights are initialized. Sorry for being late! Cool stuff with freezing layers btw, I’ve tried it with keras once and my experience was the training went faster:)

Comment: Hello @Kazuya, thank you for the quick response. It is not late. :) After re-reading your question and answer, I think it can explain my issue. I use Google pre-trained SSD-InceptionV2-Coco for the car and pedestrian detection. However, my class number is 2 but Coco has 90. So the classification layers are reset( initialized ). Then I train this loaded model with my dataset, which includes 50k images, in a short time. No wonder my evaluation result is worse than the results generated from the Google pre-trained model. I have much less dataset and shorter time for training.