# How to reuse classification layers in Tensorflow Object Detection API

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, object-detection, object-detection-api

Using Tensorflow Object Detection API with SSD_inception_v2_coco from [Tensorflow detection model zoo](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/detection_model_zoo.md),

I want to keep the original weights in classifiers' and feature-extractors' weights from the pre-trained model.

From this [discussion](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/2203),

adding `freeze_variables: ".*FeatureExtractor.*"` in train.config will freeze the feature-extractors' weights during training.

**So does it mean I have the same feature-extractors' weights in the pre-trained model?**

From this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49374984/tensorflow-object-detection-api-classification-weights-initialization-when-chan/49378863?noredirect=1#comment86940046_49378863),

if the number of classes is different from the pre-trained model,

the classifiers' weights will be initialized.

**does it mean I can have the same classifiers' weights in the pre-traind model if I use the same label map from SSD-Inception-v2-coco?**

My 3rd question is about from_detection_checkpoint in the config file.

From [configuring_jobs.md](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/configuring_jobs.md)

"from_detection_checkpoint is a boolean value. If false, it assumes the checkpoint was from an object classification checkpoint."

I guess detection checkpoint is from [Tensorflow detection model zoo](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/detection_model_zoo.md)

and classification checkpoint is from [TensorFlow-Slim image classification model library](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/slim/README.md)

Am I correct?

Thank you for precious time on my questions.

Answer (score 0):

`1. So does it mean I have the same feature-extractors' weights in the pre-trained model?`

A feature extractor and a classifier are about the same thing. They are both essentially the weights from the Inception V2 pretrained weights. If you use the Inception V2 weights as a feature extractor for SSD, then the last layer in Inception, which converts the CNN output into class probabilities, is ignored. So you can use feature extractors/classifiers trained on Imagenet, lets say, in SSD to detects objects from the COCO class list.

`2. Does it mean I can have the same classifiers' weights in the pre-
traind model if I use the same label map from SSD-Inception-v2-coco?`

And yes, the detection and classification checkpoints are from the pages you've listed.